# how to retrieve two table forign key data in one table based on primary key

Tags: asp.net, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have following three table

**File Table**

```
FileId
FileNo
```

**Payment Table**

```
  Id
  Amount
  FK_FileID
```

**Expense Table**

```
  Id
  Amount
  FK_FileID
```

I want output like

```
FileNo Payment_Amount Expense_Amount
10001         220          150
10001         120          NULL
10001         150          NULL
```

I want to retrieve filewise Payment and Expense data.
I found 1 record in expense and and 3 records in payment so in expense's other row include null and vice versa

how can I??

Comment: Can you give a rule for why the payment amount of 220 is paired with the expense amount of 150?

Comment: no not pair.. both comes from diffrent table

Comment: I think he means what relationship do you have between the Payment and Expenses table? Otherwise there is no way of knowing which Payment Amount that the Expense Amount of 150 should be displayed next to.

Comment: @Alex Tyman their is no relationship between Payment and Expenses tables.. this two having common field which is Foreign Key of table file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following should get what you want, its a little strange, but as there are no relationships between Payments and Expenses then you have to do them separately then join. You could do this with sub SELECT statements, but I used temp tables for ease of reading.

```
SELECT              F.FileNo, F.FileId, P.Amount, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY P.FileId order by P.Id) AS Row  
INTO                #Payments
FROM                File F
INNER JOIN          Payment P ON F.FileId = P.FileId

SELECT              F.FileNo, F.FileId, E.Amount, 
                    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY E.FileId order by E.Id) AS Row  
INTO                #Expenses
FROM                File F
INNER JOIN          Expense E ON F.FileId = E.FileId

SELECT              COALESCE(tP.FileNo, tE.FileNo) AS FileNo,
                    tP.amount AS Payment_Amount,
                    tE.amount AS Expense_Amount 
FROM                #Payments tP
FULL JOIN           #Expenses tE ON tP.FileId = tE.FileId AND tP.Row = tE.Row
```

I have used ROW_NUMBER() to get a number that depends on the FileID for each of the Payment and Expense records that could belong to the given File. I then join on these values in the FULL JOIN (as well as the FileID) so that only one instance will be joined upon, this eliminates the issues that a normal INNER JOIN between the three tables would have caused.

Ordering might be an issue as it depends on which table (Payment or Expense) has the most records.

Let me know how it goes when you test it.

Answer (score 0):

Use below query ...

```
Select f.FileNo,p.Amount as Payment_Amount,e.Amount as Expense_Amount From File f inner   join        Payment p ON f.FileId = p.FK_FileID inner join Expense e on  e.FileId = p.FK_FileID
```

Comment: your query is correct.. I already try this but I want other expence as null but your query give following output                   **FileNo  Payment_Amount  Expense_Amount**
10001         220          150
10001         120          150
10001         150          150